# This page isn’t working, HTTP ERROR 413. apache centos

Tags: apache, centos

I am trying to upload 210mb size of csv file. But i'm getting this error.

> This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 413

I've increased upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_execution_time, max_input_time in php.ini, then restarted my server. but nothing is working out. I am using httpd(apache) in centos 8. My application is build on PHP (Laravel). can anyone help me out?

Comment: You should check the apache and/or php logs and see what's there. There should be an error message of some sort somewhere...

Comment: @BogdanStoica There wasn't any error in any log file. Though i solved it. after changing those in my php.ini it wasn't effecting even if i restarted my apache, in another forum i found that i have to restart my php-fpm.